# Why does cyclo heptyl carbocation is unstable?

Tags: organic-chemistry

When cyclo propane methyl carbocation under goes ring expansion it gives cyclo butyl carbocation, similarly when cyclo butyl methyl undergoes ring expansion it gives cyclo pentyl carbocation.  My question is why cyclo hexyl methyl do note under goes ring expansion?

Comment: Why would it?$\,$

Comment: Let's put it this way: it doesn't expand, because it doesn't have a reason to. Smaller cycles, on the other hand, ***do*** have such a reason.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why cyclohexylmethyl (carbocation?) do not undergoes ring expansion (cycloheptyl carbocation)?

Is above statement that you mean in your question? If so, it is easy to answer. If you look at ring stability, the lowest ring strain is given by cyclohexyl ring system by adopting to a chair conformation. Therefore, there is no such thing that thermodynamically more stable form will spontaneously transform to thermodynamically more unstable form (relatively speaking). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_strain), strain energy of cyclohexane is about $\pu{0.1 kcal mol-1}$ (not much different from methylcyclohexane), thus thermodynamically more stable than cycloheptane, the strain energy of which is listed as $\pu{6.2 kcal mol-1}$.

To support this phenomenon, I have solid experimental evidence: During my Ph.D. studies, I have observed Friedel-Crafts alkylation of toluene in details using tosic acid as a catalyst and alkenes including allyl and cinnamyl bromides, cycloalkenes, tosylates, etc. as the alkyl substrate (Ref.1). The frequent reactions using cycloheptene gives 100% 4-(1-methylcyclohenyl)-1-methylbenzene exclusively. No traces of 4-cycloheptyltoluene at all!

**References:**

1. Mathew P. D. Mahindaratne and Kandatege Wimalasena, "Detailed Characterization of p-Toluenesulfonic Acid Monohydrate as a Convenient, Recoverable, Safe, and Selective Catalyst for Alkylation of the Aromatic Nucleus," *J. Org. Chem.* **1998**, *63(9)*, 2858–2866 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo971832r).